# is there a way to store my svelte store in local storage so it doesn't reset on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, svelte, sveltekit

the content I fetch from my svelte store disappears on page refresh, is there a way to stop it from resetting so it can stay on the page even when i reload? sorry if the question is a little vague im not sure how to really phrase it.

svelte store

```
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

export const leagueTable = writable([]);

const fetchTable = async () => {
    const url = `https://soccer.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0/standings/season/19734?api_token=API_KEY`;
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const data = await res.json();
    leagueTable.set(data.data);
}
fetchTable();
```

component

```
<script>
    import { leagueTable } from "../stores/league-standings-stores"
    console.log($leagueTable)
    const tableMaps = $leagueTable.map($leagueTable => $leagueTable.standings.data).flat();
    console.log(tableMaps)
</script>

{#each tablePositions as tablePosition}
  <div class="standings-table flex gap-9 mb-2 pb-4 pt-3 border-b border-[#303041]">
       <div class="team-details flex gap-4 w-full" id="td">
        <p class="w-[18px]">{tablePosition.position}</p>
         <img src="{tablePosition.team.data.logo_path}" alt="" class="w-[1.5em] object-scale-down">
          <p class="">{tablePosition.team_name}</p>
      </div>

      <div class="team-stats flex gap-5 text-left child:w-5 child:text-center w-full">
        <p>{tablePosition.overall.games_played}</p>
        <p>{tablePosition.overall.won}</p>
        <p>{tablePosition.overall.draw}</p>
        <p>{tablePosition.overall.lost}</p>
        <p>{tablePosition.overall.goals_scored}</p>
        <p>{tablePosition.overall.goals_against}</p>
        <p>{tablePosition.total.goal_difference}</p>
        <p>{tablePosition.overall.points}</p>
        <p class="!w-[78px] !text-left">{tablePosition.recent_form}</p>
      </div>
 </div>
{/each}
```

Comment: You could try this https://github.com/joshnuss/svelte-local-storage-store there are also workarounds to do the same thing yourself, but it's pretty much what this package does.

Answer (score 2):

Check if localstorage data exists:

```
let localData = localStorage.getItem("leagueTable")
export const leagueTable = writable(localData ? JSON.parse(localData) : []);
```

Save to local storage and keep in sync with store:

```
$: {
    localStorage.setItem("leagueTable", JSON.stringify($leagueTable))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [github.com/joshnuss/svelte-local-storage-store](https://github.com/joshnuss/svelte-local-storage-store)

```
npm install svelte-local-storage-store
```

Then, inside your store page, usually a js file:

```
import { persisted } from 'svelte-local-storage-store'

export const leagueTable = persisted('leagueTable', [])
```

In your svelte page you can use it as:

```
import {leagueTable} from './stores'
```

Use as you wish

```
leagueTable.subscribe(...) // subscribe to changes
leagueTable.update(...) // update value
leagueTable.set(...) // set value
get(leagueTable) // read value
$leagueTable // read value with automatic subscription
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).